# How to make distributed builds using XCode 3.2 on OS X 10.6

Tags: xcode, macos, build-process, build, distributed

After I upgraded using a clean install from OS X 10.5 to 10.6.2 and upgraded the XCode to 3.2.1 I wasn't able to use distributed builds feature anymore.

There are several issues that I detected:

- In most cases Bonjour is not detecting the other computers even they are on the same switch.
- I added a custom 'set' where I added manually the IP addreses of each computer. Even so I still get status: "unreachable" on them.BTW, ping does work without problems.

Both `share my computer for shared workgroup builds (distcc)` and `distribute builds via shared workgroup builds` options are checked.

http://nusunt.eu/download/xcode_312_distcc.png

Comment: I updated the question - I was referring to 3.2.1, the latest XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple just release XCode 3.2.2 that is solving this problem. If you cannot upgrade you should try the workaround [How to make distributed builds using XCode 3.2 on OS X 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900681/how-to-make-distributed-builds-using-xcode-3-2-on-os-x-10-6/2051307#2051307)

Answer (score 1):

The solution seems to be to run Xcode in "32-bit" mode - you set this in the "Get Info" dialog in the Finder.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I submitted a bug to apple more than 2 months ago and they didn't reply to me. It's interesting to see that StackOverflow works better than Apple support.

Answer (score 0):

you really should be using Xcode 3.2.1 in 10.6, 3.1 isn't supported fully.